# Changing arguments of {} find exec

Tags: find, exec

Is it possible to change the parameters that are passed to exec in find?
For example I need to copy files under a different names: *.txt -> *.new.txt
Now I'm doing it for two commands:

```
find /root/test -name "*.txt" -exec cp {} {}.new \;
find /root/test -name "*.txt.new" -exec rename .txt.new .new.txt {} \;
```

Is it possible to parse {} to access the file extension? Something like (i don't know exactly):

```
-exec cp {} {$1}.new.txt \;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's possible doing what you're asking exactly, but it's certainly possible to perform that kind of modification to the parameter using the shell:

```
find /root/test -name "*.txt" -exec sh -c 'cp "$0" "${0%.txt}.new.txt"' "{}" \;
```

I'll try to break this down so it's a little more understandable:

```
-exec sh -c '<...>' "{}" \;
```

This starts a new shell which executes the script specified in single quotes. Also note that `"{}"` is a parameter sent to this script and will be available as `$0` within that script.

As for the script itself, `$0` is the matched text file, and we copy that to `${0%.txt}.new.txt` which takes the file name (`$0`), and trims the first text that matches `.txt` from the *END* of the file name, leaving us with a file name without an extension. Then we simply append the new file name `.new.txt`.

As an addendum, depending on what your system is like, you may get a "substitution error" message (I got this on my Mint install, but not on my CentOS install). If you do, try to change `-exec sh` to `-exec bash`.