# Rename files using the -exec action of find

Tags: bash, replace, find

I'm currently learning bash, and came upon the `find` command. I'd like to use it to, say, find and rename all .py files to .bak (for example, hello.py should be renamed hello.bak).

I think I should be able to write a command like this:

```
find -name "*.py" -exec mv {} NEW_NAME \;
```

where NEW_NAME stands for the renamed {}.

I've tried various convoluted approaches, amongst which

- assigning {} to a variable: I'm unable to do a variable assignment (`-exec a=1` for example returns an error)
- piping commands, but even though `echo $(echo ./hello.py | cut -d'.' -f2).bak` returns `/hello.bak` as expected, replacing NEW_NAME with `$(echo {} | cut -d'.' -f2).bak` doesn't.
- Finally (thanks to the following link: [Changing arguments of {} find exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23626842/changing-arguments-of-find-exec) ), I was able to achieve my goal with `find -name "*.py" -exec bash -c 'mv $0 ${0/.py/.bak}' "{}" \;`

I have a feeling though that there's a simpler way to do this, and that I'm overlooking something obvious.

Edit: I'm aware there are other ways to batch rename files than with `find ... -exec ...`; I'm specifically looking for a better/simpler way to do this  with this command (I was hoping for some Linux equivalent to Python's `.replace()` string method).

Comment: There are a bunch of different ways to rename things in linux.  See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030 for some options in addition to `find`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments; @j_b: I know there are other ways, but I was specifically looking for a method using `find ... -exec ...` (hopefully simpler than the one I found).

Answer (score 5):

You're not missing anything, the UNIX way of doing it is like so:

```
find . -type f -name '*.py' -exec sh -c '
for src; do
  mv "$src" "${src%.*}.bak"
done' sh {} +
```

Comment: Thanks, so it seems there's nothing really simpler than what I already arrived to. I was hoping for some Linux equivalent o Python's `.replace()`.

Comment: There are third-party `rename` commands which work this way, but nothing completely standard, as in POSIX. In fact, there are multiple `rename` commands with different features and different syntax.